# Create log in azure

Tags: logging, azure-web-app-service, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've created a custom chat using html n Javascript. It works as follows

```
User enters a question - hello
There is a rest call to Directline api 
It internally calls the Qna maker bot 
The response is displayed back.
```

My query is lets say there is an user `A`, he is using this service. Everything is working fine with the code. The request is properly triggered and the response is exactly received as expected.

When user asks some question. I want this to be stored in azure in a text format like

```
userName,  question, confidenceScore, count
```

The response I get is in this way

```
  {"answer":"confidenseScore"}
```

And my direct line call contains request data like this

```
  {
     type:"message", 
     text:"myQuestion",
     from:
         {
          id:"userId"
        }
  }
```

I've got all this information but I dunno how am I supposed to create a log in the above format. Please let me know how can I do this. A documentation or an example would be helpful.

I'm asking this, as this is some sort of chat bot that lists faqs in a side. And I want this to be on user basis, I mean user A logs in, faqs are to be generated based on what this user asked earlier.

Thanks

Comment: Can someone please share why the close flag is on?

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you could leverage [Azure Table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage) and use Azure Storage SDK for your development language to store/retrieve the detailed questions information based on the specific user. Also, you could leverage the official tool [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to manage your table storage. For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer).